# Why are single numbers sometimes written in brackets, as in $(2x)+(-4) +(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Why, in some expressions, are numbers written in brackets? like
$$(2x)+(-4) +(x)$$

Comment: Usually in basic math nothing special.  It lets them set off the unary minus sign.  Otherwise, they owe you an explanation in the text.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually used in basic math settings, for example when introducing students to working with negative integers, as in $5+(-2)$ (writing $5-2$ would mean a subtraction to them). It may also be used when writing fractions (with $/$) when it could be ambiguous otherwise, for example, $3/(x+y)$. It can be removed (by taking care of the signs or using fraction form as needed). So, $(2x)+(-4)+(x)$ can be written as $2x-4+x$, and $3/(x+y)$ as $\frac{3}{x+y}$.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is essential for some equations, e.g.,

$(-5)(-4)$

Imagine taking the term without parentheses!